Calculating required retirement savings per year
Let’s say I want to have $1,000,000$ dollars $T$ saved in an account in $30$ years time $y$. Each year I will contribute $1\ \%$ $f$ more than the last year and each year my total account balance will earn interest $r$.
How do I calculate the first contribution that I need to make in order for the sum to be $1,000,000$ ?. Well this part I have figured out. I’m not a mathematician but I had help solving this;
$$
a_{0} =
\frac{T}{\sum_{i = 0}^{y}
\left[\left(1 + r\right)^{i}
\left(1 + f\right)^{y - i}\right]}
$$
\begin{align}
\mbox{So for example:}\quad
T & = 1,000,000,\
y = 30,\ r = 0.02,\ f = 0.01
\\[2mm]
\mbox{Then}\quad a_{0} & = 21,574.3833
\end{align}
If we have an account that starts at $0\ \$$ and each year we first compound the account by in this case $2\ \%$ $\left(\times1.02\right)$ and then add the deposit compounded by $1\ \%$ from the previous year, the account will end up at $1,000,000$ after $30$ years. This is tested and works.
My question is:

What is the formula / how do I solve this if the account starts with for example $50,000$ in it ?. What would the first payment look like then ?.


The backwards formula for interest rate $i/100$ and saving rate r with $1/100$ increase per year is
$$S_{t+1}=\left(\frac{i}{100}+1\right) S_t+r \left(\frac{t}{100}+1\right)\ \to \ S_t  \ = \ \frac{S_{t+1} - r \ (t \ + \ 100 )  }{100+i}$$
Instead of backward devaluation algebrically, simply define in Mathematica e.g.
 i = 3/100; r = 20000;

an automatic rollback
 S[t_?(# > 0 &)] :=  S[t] = 1/103 (-100 r - r t + 100 S[t + 1])

The double 'definition :=' with a 'setting ='  automatically fixes the values evaluated during the recursion process in memory, avoiding repeated recursions.
 S[30] = 1000000

 S[2] // Together // N // Expand
 10782.6
 S[1] // N
 -9143.15 

Try it in Wolfram alpha, Python
If you want a closed algebraic formula set
  S[10]=1
  S[t_?(# > 0 &)] :=  S[t] = ip  (  S[t + 1] - r (1 + t q))

with the inverse interest factor $\text{ip} \ \ 1/(1+i/100)$
then you get with some simplifications
$$S[1] = \text{ip}\cdot \left(\frac{1-\text{ip}^9}{1-\text{ip}}+q\cdot r\cdot (\text{ip} (\text{ip} (\text{ip} (\text{ip} (\text{ip} (\text{ip} (\text{ip} (9 \text{ip}+8)+7)+6)+5)+4)+3)+2)+1)\right)$$
Ok, want the simple forward formula with $z=1+i$ interest factor per year and p percentage increase of payment $s$ per year
$$S(S_{p,z}(s,n)=\sum _{k=0}^n s \ (k\ p \ +  \ 1) \ z^{n-k}\ = \ \frac{s \left(z^{n+1} (p+z-1)-z (n p+p+1)+n p+1\right)}{(z-1)^2}$$
yields e.g
$$S_{1.03,0.01}(20000,30) \ = \ 1.12674 \ 10^6$$
To solve backwards
$$\text{Solve}\left(S_{1.03,0.01}(s,n) \ = \ 10^6 , s\right)  \quad s \to \frac{22500.}{-0.0075 n+1.03^{n+1}-1.0075}$$
Starting with $s= 17759.$
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 17759. & 17759. \\
 35695.6 & 36228.4 \\
 53632.2 & 55429.4 \\
 71568.8 & 75384. \\
 89505.4 & 96114.9 \\
 107442. & 117645. \\
 125379. & 139999. \\
 143315. & 163201. \\
 161252. & 187277. \\
 179188. & 212253. \\
 197125. & 238155. \\
 215061. & 265012. \\
 232998. & 292853. \\
 250935. & 321706. \\
 268871. & 351602. \\
 286808. & 382573. \\
 304744. & 414651. \\
 322681. & 447869. \\
 340618. & 482260. \\
 358554. & 517861. \\
 376491. & 554708. \\
 394427. & 592838. \\
 412364. & 632289. \\
 430301. & 673101. \\
 448237. & 715315. \\
 466174. & 758973. \\
 484110. & 804119. \\
 502047. & 850796. \\
 519984. & 899052. \\
 537920. & 948932. \\
 555857. & 1.00049\times 10^6 \\
\end{array}
 $$
 ListPlot[Table[{j, S[17759, 1.03`, 0.01`][j]}, {j, 0, 30}]]



So if I have T=1,000,000, y=30 ,r=0.02, f=0.01 and a starting value of 50000 how do I get $a_0$?

You gave me a formula that I don't need because I already have a version of it with compound growth included. Did you even read my post? This solved nothing and isn't even related to what I asked..

If you already have an amount $P_0$ in your account, it will grow to $T_0 = P_0 \cdot (1+r)^y$ in $y$ years. Then you only have to save $T-T_0$. You can therefore multiply  the initial annual amount $a_0$ by the factor $1 - T_0/T$.
In this case, assuming still $r = 0.02$, the initial \$50,000 will grow to \$90,586 after 30 years. That's 9.0568 % of your goal. You don't need to save this amount yourself and therefore can start with $(1-.090568)\cdot a_0 = 19,620$.
